# render text convert strings in ror

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, render

I'm rendering json without object title. So I tried to render it as text as follows

```
 render :text=>
          [{
          "id": "0",
          "heading": "Trending this Week",
          "title": "Prost Brew Pub",
          "place": "Sholinganallur",
          "image": "http://192.168.0.103/test2/blur.jpg",
          "rating": 4.3,
          "amount": "Rs. 1800 for two people",
          "review": "320 Reviews",
          "photos": "630 Photos",
          "genre": ["British", "Mexican", "Continental"]
},...
```

It convert the above as following

```
[{:id=>"0", :heading=>"Trending this Week", :title=>"Prost Brew Pub", :place=>"Sholinganallur", :image=>"http://192.168.0.103/test2/blur.jpg", :rating=>4.3, :amount=>"Rs. 1800 for two people", :review=>"320 Reviews", :photos=>"630 Photos", :genre=>["British", "Mexican", "Continental"]}
```

why did it convert the `"id": "0"` to `:id=>"0"` ?

How can I render the above array without any change? thanks in advance.

Is there and render method available to get the object without it's title?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your ":text" is an array is of Hashes. So Ruby is rendering it in Hash syntax. If you want json you should render `json` not `text`.

```
render json: @object, status: :ok
```